# Use standard output from .Net application with powershell's Out-GridView

Tags: powershell

Simple question: is it possible to use the output of a .net application and pipe it through Out-GridView in powershell ?

Say for example I have a C# console application that does something like this :

```
Console.WriteLine("col1-value \t col2-value \t col3-value");
Console.WriteLine("col1-value \t col2-value \t col3-value");
```

Is it possible to pipe the ouput to Out-GridView and separate everything in different named columns ? How does it work otherwise ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect the output of you C# program into a file:

```
csharp.exe > $env:temp\foo.txt
```

Then use a script like this to read the content of the file and display it in the Grid-Window:

```
$Columns = "Col1", "Col2", "Col3"
Get-Content $env:temp\foo.txt | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $Columns -Delimiter "`t" | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Not exactly what I hopped would be the easiest way to approach the problem, but I guess that it's close enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are fundamentally misunderstanding how powershell works in general.

It is designed to with objects as its primary way of dealing with things, not text strings.

If you want to make this work, you can take the strings, use the `.Split()` function to make them distinct, and get it to work that way, but it not an optimal situation.

Comment: To tell the truth, I knew ps was working with object but I was wondering if there was any way to pass objects from console applications to powershell ... I guess not. The problem with this is that you can only use powershell objects to powershell. You cannot interact with any other applications ...

Comment: @Erick its not the case. Powershell can use all .NET objects from applications without issues. You might want to look at something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/742308/725709 as an extreme example